# Heroku deployment causing app to crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-1.9.3

Here is my heroku deployment log, can anyone help me whats going wrong ? I am deploying my first rails app. can anyone tell what is causing the app to crash ?

(edited to format the log, updated log after running heroku run rake db:migrate, edited after putting gmaps4rails under production)

```
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/estates_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.644855+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.648188+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `acts_as_gmappable' for #<Class:0x0000000346c578> (NoMethodError)
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/estate.rb:18:in `<class:Estate>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/estate.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.645907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.646227+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-08-02T16:09:34.647286+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-08-02T16:09:36.386636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-02T16:09:36.411861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-02T16:09:37.288150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=powerful-brook-9708.herokuapp.com fwd="68.100.86.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-02T16:10:06.258553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=powerful-brook-9708.herokuapp.com fwd="68.100.86.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was at first I did not mention the gmaps4rails in production, later did not rake the db:migrate and finally the main problem was that I had the application running in production mode on localhost so that was causing some problem when I was trying to push it into heroku. So I close the local host, and pushed the app and it started working.